# unable to perform a POST (Update is not allowed for this operation)

Tags: angular, symfony, api-platform.com

I decided to start learning Angular (I'm on version 15.0.3) and do some CRUD.
My application is well connected to my api (I use api-platform via Symfony), the method
GetCollection() works.

On the other hand, as soon as I have finished setting up the Post() method, I get this message: Update is not allowed for this operation.
I have done various searches, but nothing has solved my problem.
Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

> Here is my entity

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SerieRepository::class)]
#[
    ApiResource(
        operations: [
            new Meta\GetCollection(),
            new Meta\Post(),
            new Meta\Get(
                uriTemplate: '/series/name/{name}',
                uriVariables: 'name'
            ),
            new Meta\Get(),
            new Meta\Patch(),
            new Meta\Delete()
        ],
        normalizationContext: [
            'groups' => ['series:read']
        ],
        denormalizationContext: [
            'groups' => ['series:post']
        ],
    )
]
class Serie
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\GeneratedValue,
        ORM\Column,
        Meta\ApiProperty(identifier: true),
        Groups(['series:read','books:read'])
    ]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[
        ORM\Column(length: 100, unique: true),
        Groups(['series:read','series:post','books:read'])
    ]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[
        ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'serie', targetEntity: Book::class),
        Groups(['series:read'])
    ]
    private Collection $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }
[...]
```

> The service for the entity

```
create(serie: Serie): Observable<Serie> {
  return this.http.post<Serie>(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/series', 
    serie, 
    {
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      responseType: "json",
    }  
  )
}
```

> And the component

```
export class SeriesPostComponent {
  serie: Serie;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private serieService: SerieService, private snackBar: SnackBarComponent) {
    this.serie = new Serie(0,"",[]);
  }

  nameFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({ firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required], });

  addSerie(): void {
    this.serie.name = this.nameFormGroup.value.firstCtrl ?? '';
    this.serieService.create(this.serie as Serie).subscribe(
      data => { this.snackBar.successSnackBar(`la série < ${data.name} > à été ajouté`) },
      echec => {  
        this.snackBar.errorSnackBar(echec.error.detail) 
        console.log(echec);
        
      }
    );
  } 
}
```

Edit:
Put(), Get(), Delete() methods work. But still no Post()

Edit*:
I changed my service creation method to this

```
  create(serie: Serie): Observable<Serie> {
    return this.http.post<Serie>(
      this.seriesurl, 
      {
        'name': serie.name
      }, 
      {
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        responseType: "json",
      }
    )
  }
```

And it worked.
Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: I'm not sure and I'm not familiar with Api platform , but it can be beause the absence of new Put()

Comment: adding Put() does not change anything

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you pass "id" field in request and ItemNormalizer class from API Platform throws that error - it's a known issue, you can find it(and a solution) on github
Or simply do not pass "id" field - exclude it, rename it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with phpunit and postman api tests. Fixed by setting header variable **Content-Type : application/ld+json**

[image]

[image]